# Exporting Long Integer to CSV

Tags: r, csv, export

I am trying to export a `data.frame` which has 2 columns having 16 and 24 long integers.

However after exporting to csv, I am getting scientific notation like `4.352370e+15` in place of original non-scientific integer.

**Code**

```
write.csv(fulljoin,file="output2.csv")
```

Comment: Give some sample data and maybe someone will help out quicker.

Comment: See the Details section of `?write.csv`.  It provides recommendations for how to handle this.

Comment: It helps if you state the actual question eg. 'R write.csv - why am I getting unexpected high-values from data.frame export?'. Bonus points for mentioning the actual language you're using (I'm assuming it's R?). And some data always helps otherwise it's too difficult for people to test/answer.

Comment: [great reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) are great

Comment: @Pete855217 it has an [tag:r] tag on it. It's generally accepted practice to [not use them in titles except on certain occasions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: @hrbrmstr fair enough re the R tag, although the rest of the comment still stands - the post was simply a statement. I'm assuming (guessing) it was "how can I avoid scientific notation in data.frame csv write output?". It's a useful question - scientific notation can be a PITA when handling the data further, and R can drive you a little mad when trying to do simple things like this.

Answer (score 1):

Following option worked for me. Thanks to everyone for extending help.

**options(digits=18)**

Everything else was kept constant. It helped while reading as well as while writing.

Comment: That is not a very general solution.  Try `options(digits=18); x <- 123456789012345678901234; write.csv(x, "longnumber.csv")` and you will still get scientific notation in your output.

Comment: @JohnAndrews . Very true and unfortunately not even a decent solution. Although for my purpose which was very urgent it has proven useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would not count on getting that many digits without loss of precision in the default integer data type.  Notice that the integers will actually get coerced to numeric after a certain length.  Compare `class(12345678L)` (integer) to `class(123456789012L)` (numeric with warning).  After a little more length you will start to lose precision, regardless of how many digits you are displaying:

```
option(digits=22) # the max
x <-  1234567890123456789012; x
# [1] 1234567890123456774144 -- whoops!
```

For larger integers you may want to use a different class such as `Big Integer` in `gmp`.

```
library(gmp)
x <- as.bigz("1234567890123456789012345678901234567890")
x <- x + 1 # do some math
write.csv(as.character(x), "bignumber.csv", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE) 
# csv looks like:
# x
# 1234567890123456789012345678901234567891
```